# How to Hide Google API Key And Still Use It

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-api

I am currently hosting a website on GitHub. I want to be able to use the Google Sheets API to read data from a google spreadsheet in node js. Is it a security risk to push code with the API key? Is there a way to hide it on GitHub but still be able to use it?

Comment: Does Github not have some concept of "Secret Management" where you can put the key and reference it? (EDIT: found it-- https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets -- this is probably your best bet to avoid exposing it)

Answer (score 2):

Use this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Set you API key in a `.env` file something like this

```
API=sds1sdf13s21f23sd1fs1d3f21
```

and access it via `process.env.API`

and add the `.env` file to the `.gitignore`